# File.WriteAllBytes generates one pdf fine, but multiple pdfs with errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf-generation, itext

I have a loop that goes through some data and generates pdf files.  if I generate one pdf by iteself, it works just fine (the pdf opens), but if I create 2 pdf files, the first one will open fine, but the second one will display and error saying the file is corrupt or something similar.  Is there something I am doing wrong in the loop with the stream, etc?

```
foreach (report r reports)
{
      byte[] pdf;
      ReportName = r.ReportName;

      switch (r.ReportId.ToLower())
      {
           case "pdf":
                pdfBuilder = new pdfHelper(candidate, 
                pdfTemplates[(Guid)case_report.TemplateId], r.XMLFieldData, DCFormats,  
                              r.ProjectReportName, dependants, DepCount, SpoCount);
                                            pdf = pdfBuilder.GenerateCasePDF();

           break;


        }
        //Add Bookmarks for each report in candidate
        ChapterCount++;
        ChapterReport = new Chapter(new Paragraph(case_report.ReportName), ChapterCount);
        tDoc.Add(ChapterReport);

        reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        n = reader.NumberOfPages;

        for (int page = 1; page <= n; page++)
            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, page));

        copy.FreeReader(reader);
        reader.Close();
 }
 //Save pdf to folder
 ReportName = null;
 tDoc.Close();

 PubResult = outputStream.ToArray();

 File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}.pdf", JobRootPath, CaseFileName), PubResult);



  //Reset for next case
  outputStream = new MemoryStream();
  tDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
  copy = new PdfSmartCopy(tDoc, outputStream);
  copy.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.PageModeUseOutlines;
  copy.SetFullCompression();
  tDoc.Open();

}
```

Comment: It seems you are saving the pdf to the folder after creating each report. What if you save each report to the folder individually?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing *ChapterCount* should get reset to its initial value like all the other variables you're resetting at the end of your for loop.

That aside, I'd recommend moving the body of your *for* loop, and all related variables, into a new method.  Reusing variables tends to lead to errors like this.

Comment: ChapterCount is getting reset, just at the beginning of the loop